# T-SQL sort integer values

Tags: sql, sorting, integer

I'd like to create a procedure which later will have 5 integer parameters as an input. Within these procedure I want to sort those integer values in ascending order and later update a table. I did it with case whens so that I don't lose the information of each parameter (Background: Additional to this, each parameter is connected to a string which I need so sort in the same order. But sorting those integer first is faster.)

Somehow I can't get the sorting for the middle part. Min and Max Value works fine:

```
DECLARE @tableX TABLE(c1 INT, c2 INT, c3 INT, c4 INT, c5 INT);

INSERT @tableX(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) 

SELECT 2,1,3,0,1
UNION ALL SELECT 3,4,5,2,2
UNION ALL SELECT 5,4,3,1,1
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1,2,0,10;

SELECT 
    --int1
    c1 = CASE
  WHEN c1 >= c2 AND c1 >= c3 AND c1 >= c4 AND c1 >= c5 THEN c1
  WHEN c2 >= c1 AND c2 >= c3 AND c2 >= c4 AND c2 >= c5 THEN c2
  WHEN c3 >= c1 AND c3 >= c2 AND c3 >= c4 AND c3 >= c5 THEN c3
  WHEN c4 >= c1 AND c4 >= c2 AND c4 >= c3 AND c4 >= c5 THEN c4
  ELSE c5 END,

    --int2
    --c2 = CASE 
 -- WHEN c1 >= c2 AND c1 >= c3 AND c1 >= c4 AND c1 >= c5 THEN   
 --   CASE WHEN c2 >= c3 AND c2 >= c4 AND c2 >= c5 THEN c2 ELSE
    --  CASE WHEN c3 >= c2 AND c3 >= c5 THEN 
    --      CASE WHEN c4 >= c5 THEN 

 -- WHEN c2 >= c3 AND c2 >= c4 AND c2 >= c5 THEN   
 --   CASE WHEN c2 >= c3 AND c2 >= c4 AND c2 >= c5 THEN c2 END


    --ELSE
    --CASE WHEN c3 >= c2 AND c3 >= c4 AND c3 >= c5 THEN c3 ELSE
    --CASE WHEN c4 >= c5 THEN c4 ELSE c5 END END END END,    

    --int3
    c3 = NULL,


    --in4
    c4 = NULL,

    --in5
    c5 = CASE
  WHEN c1 <= c2 AND c1 <= c3 AND c1 <= c4 AND c1 <= c5 THEN c1
  WHEN c2 <= c1 AND c2 <= c3 AND c2 <= c4 AND c2 <= c5 THEN c2
  WHEN c3 <= c1 AND c3 <= c2 AND c3 <= c4 AND c3 <= c5 THEN c3
  WHEN c4 <= c1 AND c4 <= c2 AND c4 <= c3 AND c4 <= c5 THEN c4
  ELSE c5 END

FROM @tableX;
```

Can someone give a hint for the middle part?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL.)

Comment: Sorry it is T-SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly how you want to use the sorted integers, but why not let SQL do the sorting for you?  the below, creates a temp table (`@s`), with the five integers (passed in as parameters?) in it and sorts them.

```
declare @ip1 int = 2 
declare @ip2 int = 1 
declare @ip3 int = 3 
declare @ip4 int = 0 
declare @ip5 int = 1 


declare @s table (v int)
INSERT @s(v) 
values((@ip1)), ((@ip2)), ((@ip3)), ((@ip4)), ((@ip5))
insert 
select v from @s order by v
```

What you do in the stored proc with this sorted list is another question...

Ok, here's a script to try and work through. It is T-SQL. Please run it and look at the output. the first part creates a dummy table To represent your table and populates it with some data. It assumes that your table has an integer Primary Key.

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.sortTbl
  ( id int IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key NOT NULL,
    i1 int NOT NULL, i2 int NOT NULL, i3 int NOT NULL, 
    i4 int NOT NULL, i5 int NOT NULL,
    s1 varchar(20) NULL, s2 varchar(20) NULL, s3 varchar(20) NULL,
    s4 varchar(20) NULL, s5 varchar(20) NULL)
 insert sortTbl(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5)
 Values ((3), (1), (0), (5), (7), ('fog'), ('snap'), ('dead'), ('yellow'), ('lox')), 
        ((6), (2), (12), (1), (8),('tree'), ('saw'), ('earn'), ('ran'), ('que')), 
        ((5), (6), (0), (2), (3),('like'), ('car'), ('hood'), ('wash'), ('man'))
```

The next part is the script that generates the extra ten columns from the data in this sample table (`sortTbl'). It works even if the original values are not only 1 through 5, but within each row there should not be duplicates.

```
 declare @T table (id int primary key not null,
    ni1 int null, ni2 int null, ni3 int null, 
    ni4 int null, ni5 int null, 
    ns1 varchar(20) null, ns2 varchar(20) null, 
    ns3 varchar(20) null, ns4 varchar(20) null, 
    ns5 varchar(20) null)
 insert @t(id) select id from sortTbl
 declare @d table (id int, val int, strVal varchar(20))
 declare @id int = 0
 declare @S table (rn int  primary key identity not null, 
         id int, colOrder int null, val int, strVal varchar(20))
 While exists (Select * from @t 
               Where id > @id) Begin
    select @id = Min(id) 
    from sortTbl where id > @id
    insert @d(id, val, strVal)
    Select @id, i1, s1 From sortTbl where id = @id union
    Select @id, i2, s2 From sortTbl where id = @id union
    Select @id, i3, s3 From sortTbl where id = @id union
    Select @id, i4, s4 From sortTbl where id = @id union
    Select @id, i5, s5 From sortTbl where id = @id 
    -- -------------------------------------------
    Insert @s(id, val, strVal)
    Select id, val, strVal from @d
    order by val
    Delete @d
 end
 Update s set colOrder  = 
    (Select Count(*) from @s 
     Where id = s.id 
        and rn <= s.rn)   
 From @s s

 Select a.Id, 
    c1.Val, c1.strVal,
    c2.Val, c2.strVal,
    c3.Val, c3.strVal,
    c4.Val, c4.strVal,
    c5.Val, c5.strVal
 From sortTbl a
    left join @s c1 on c1.id = a.id and c1.colOrder = 1 
    left join @s c2 on c2.id = a.id and c2.colOrder = 2
    left join @s c3 on c3.id = a.id and c3.colOrder = 3
    left join @s c4 on c4.id = a.id and c4.colOrder = 4
    left join @s c5 on c5.id = a.id and c5.colOrder = 5
```

Comment: I have a table with some million data. What I need is to order the content in columns in asc order (based on rows, ill put in a cursor later). 
Example:
int = {10,2,3,0,0}
string = {a,b,c,d,e}
To those integer belongs also a string wich is written in a separate column (pair sorting?)

Result:
my table with exactly 10 new columns in which i can put these ordered content.

Comment: You want to add 10 new columns to an existing table, and populate these columns with the data from 5 existing columns, in a specific order based on sort order of integers in another 5 existing columns?  Please clarify exactly what you are trying to do, I am still not clear.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I'll explain it in more details: The existing table got 5 int values. But to each int value also belongs a string which is written in a separate column. So in total I have 10 filled input columns. Columns name are for example i1,i2,i3,i4,i5 filled with int values and s1,s2,s3,s4,s5 filled with a string. Pairs are i1,s1 then i2,s2 and so on. Now I want to sort them asc and write them in 10 new columns.  If i5 is min value of all integer it should come in nc_i1 and automatically write down the pair string s5 in nc_s1. If i3 comes next put it in nc_i2 and s3 in nc_s2... I hope I explained it well

Comment: In that case, won't `nc_i1`through `nc_i5` always be values 1-5?   Also, is there a unique key on this table ?

Comment: Yes exactly, but only if the input contains values from 1-5. Inside the columns are alot of unsorted random values.

Another integer example:
`i1-i5 = {0,155,33,12,9}`
`nc_i1 - nc_i5 = {0,9,12,33,155}`

And there exist an unique key as well.

Comment: Then why do you need those columns in the result (if they are always the same, then they add nothing of value)

Comment: I totally get your point. But once I'm done with my transformations I export each of these pairs in different tables. Therefore I need to choose the right pair and it's easier if they are already ordered in this base table.

Comment: I'm not sure you get my point. If they are always the same, then there's no difference between `Select id, nc_i1, nc_i2, nc_13, nc_i4, nc_i5 from table`  and `Select id, 1 as nc_i1, 2 as nc_i2, 3 as nc_i3, 4 as nc_i4, 5 as nc_i5 from table` Where the columns are not in the table at all

Comment: I get it, but the goal of your script is exactly what I need. I will try to implement it into my code. Thanks alot!

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, but i have one more question. So far i implemented your script and it seems to work fine. I noticed that from time to time i got duplicate integer values within a row. In that case only 1 of these duplicate values will be filled into the new columns. 

Is there a way to take those into account as well? Thanks in advance

Comment: I just ran my script for the scenario you describe, and it worked then as well.  I added another row of data to `sortTbl` with values `((5), (6), (5), (2), (4),('yelp'), ('card'), ('hall'), ('wolf'), ('money'))`  which has two `5`s in it, and both `card` and `wolf` showed up in the results, in the 3rd and 4th positions as they should have.  So you have probably implemented the solution imperfectly.

Comment: The only thing I changed is the data type for the string var's. Since i also have for each string var a code id, i thought it would be faster to use this code id instead.

Of course i also changed the datatype in the parameter tables @d,@s and @t

Example with values:
`` ((10), (10), (8), (8), (3),(4), (4), (5), (5), (7))``

i get the results:

`` 7 3 7 8 5 10 4 NULL NULL NULL NULL`` (The first 7 is the ID, then comes the pairs val, strVal)